# I can't get other user comments on my video with facebook graphs API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, video-streaming, comments

i'm used facebook graphs API for get comments on my video but when i send request it's response only my comments on video. What should I do to get all comments?

*this is url* : `https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/{video_id}/comments?access_token={ac_token}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v11.0/object/comments) (under the **limitation** section) that the user can only get info for his comments because the other users comments are not avaiable due to privacy restrictions.

Comment: thank you so much,Would it be possible for other comments by new way?

Comment: @winny actually I don't know because I did not explore the comment section deeply, but I'll let you know if I'll find something useful!